# Self Referencing Many-To-Many Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a datatable like this:

```
MtoM
{
   ParentID, 
   ChildID
}

Item
{
    ID,
    Data,
    Label
}
```

How do I write a linq query that returns every ChildID under a given ParentID and the associated Data and Label for each of these decendent IDs.  If I were using SQL I'd use a `union all` and `inner join`, but I don't know linq well enough to do this.

Performance is absolutely not an issue as there will be at most 3 levels of nesting and only 1 or 2 items in each level.  The DDL I'm trying to populate is rarely used and is not mission critical.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that child id is refering ID field in items table u can write following query to fetch required records

```
from mt in MToM 
where mt.ParentID == GivenParentID
join it in Item on mt.ChildId equals it.ID
select new { parentID = mt.ParentID, childID = it.ID, childData = it.Data, childLabel = it.Label}
```

data is being returned in anonymous type. u can create new Type and populate it with resultant records